# Extract the string between delimiters and populate into columns

Tags: mysql, talend

I have a source table with data like:

```
columndata list
abc        Paul;Michael;Benjamin;Latif
def        High;Medium;Low;NULL
ghi        Yes;No;Yes;No
```

I would like to get the output in the target table (columns are already defined) like below:

```
abc      def    ghi  (column names)
Paul     High   Yes
Michael  Medium No
Benjamin Low    Yes
Latif    NULL   No
```

Is there any simple way to extract the delimited data and load into repective columns in the target table
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a `tNormalize` and `tPivotToColumnsDelimited`.

[image]

`tNormalize` will break the list into individual elements:

[image]

Select the column to normalize (the list of values) and their separator. The output of this component looks like this:

```
|=--+-------=|
|col|values  |
|=--+-------=|
|abc|Paul    |
|abc|Michael |
|abc|Benjamin|
|abc|Latif   |
|def|High    |
|def|Medium  |
|def|Low     |
|def|NULL    |
|ghi|Yes     |
|ghi|No      |
|ghi|Yes     |
|ghi|No      |
'---+--------'
```

Next, in tMap, assign a position to each field in order to construct the target row (We need to know that the first row contains "Paul" in column abc, "High" in column def and "Yes" in column ghi.. etc)
I use this sequence:

```
Numeric.sequence("seq_" + row4.col, 1, 1)
```

[image]

This will reset the sequence for every new column.

Lastly, `tPivotToColumnsDelimited` will pivot the data:
[image]

You then read the file generated by `tPivotToColumnsDelimited` and load it into your target table.

Comment: Thank you @ibrahim. This is the best solution